# variable not changing in while loop

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop

I am trying challenges in order to practice, learn, and better understand coding. I came across a hard and decided to try it, just to see. It has no time limit luckily. The challenge was (you can skip if you wish)

"Using the JavaScript language, have the function KaprekarsConstant(num) take the num parameter being passed which will be a 4-digit number with at least two distinct digits. Your program should perform the following routine on the number: Arrange the digits in descending order and in ascending order (adding zeroes to fit it to a 4-digit number), and subtract the smaller number from the bigger number. Then repeat the previous step. Performing this routine will always cause you to reach a fixed number: 6174. Then performing the routine on 6174 will always give you 6174 (7641 - 1467 = 6174). Your program should return the number of times this routine must be performed until 6174 is reached. For example: if num is 3524 your program should return 3 because of the following steps: (1) 5432 - 2345 = 3087, (2) 8730 - 0378 = 8352, (3) 8532 - 2358 = 6174."

(coderbyte)

After working for a long while, I had found something that I imagined would work. I could not test the loop yet though, because if I did I could not rerun the code, because the loop was incomplete and would never finish processing. After it was all finished, I tested it. And I got 0, no matter what I tried. If I entered letters I got an error, what should happen, but no matter what numbers I put, even the 4 digit one from the example.

Here is my code:

```js
function KaprekarsConstant(num) { 
   var forD = [];
    var sNum = num.toString();
    var result = 0;
    var chngdN = [];
    var trkr = 0;
    
for (var i = 0; i < sNum.length; i ++) {
  forD.push(+sNum.charAt(i));
}

for (var j = 0; j < sNum.length; j ++) {
  chngdN.push(+sNum.charAt(j));
}
        while(while(forD-chngdN === trkr){
    forD = trkr.toString();
    chngdN = trkr.toString();
    forD = forD.split("");
    chngdN = chngdN.split("");
    forD = forD.sort();
    chngdN = chngdN.sort();
    forD = forD.reverse();
    forD = forD.join("");
    chngdN = chngdN.join("");
    forD = parseFloat(forD);
    chngdN = parseFloat(chngdN);
    trkr = forD - chngdN;
    forD = trkr.toString();
    chngdN = trkr.toString();
    result = result +1;
}
  // code goes here  
  return result; 
         
}
   
// keep this function call here 
KaprekarsConstant(readline());
```

I am just starting, so I really do not know what is wrong here. I would love it if someone could tell me what was wrong. (I know that it sounds like I'm trying to seem like I don't understand any of it, but I really just don't have a firm grasp on everything I've learned yet. I learned it all in a short time).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following will solve the problem, first version was not actually an implementation of the requirements but this one is.

I used the following for this:

1. Recursion (function calling itself until desired result)
2. [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [Number.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to make sure the number string is 4 characters long.
3. [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with direction that is an argument for sortNum to sort ascending or descending.

```js
    const makeAtLeast4 = num =>
      //number to string make sure you have a string that's 4 characters (add 0 if not)
      num.toString() + 
        Array.from(//create an array from someghing
          new Array(//that something is a new array
            //the lenght of this array is 4 minus the length of the string
            4-num.toString().length),
            ()=>"0"//for each item of the array insert the string "0"
          ).join("");//join this array (num 111 will be sring "1110")
    //create ascending or descending sorted number
    //  if direction is 1 it's ascending
    const sortNum = (numString,direction) =>
      parseInt(
        (direction === 1) 
        //if direction is 1 do ? else do :
          ? numString.toString().split("").sort().join("")
          : numString.toString().split("").sort().reverse().join("")
        ,10//decimal number
      );
    //take number, sort digits descending and ascending
    //  substract ascending from descending
    const descending_minus_ascending = num => {
      const stringNum = makeAtLeast4(num);
      return sortNum(stringNum) - sortNum(stringNum,1)
    }
    const kaprekarsConstant = (num,times=0) => {
      //get result for this number
      const result = descending_minus_ascending(num);
      //if result is the same as the number, return times tried
      if(result === num){
        return times
      }
      console.log(`Try:${times+1}, result:${result}`);
      //try again with the result and increase times tried by one
      //  recursively call this function
      return kaprekarsConstant(result,times+1);
    }

    console.log(kaprekarsConstant(11))
```

**[UPDATE]**

Here is the code as a while loop, I would advice you to avoid any kind of loops until you've used recursion and array functions, these maybe take a bit longer to learn but let you write easier to understand code in the long run:

```
const kaprekarsConstant = (num) => {
  //get result for this number
  //  !! notice that result is not a constant but a var
  //  we will have keep re assigning it, this can be confusing
  //  in complex code and should be avoided if possible
  //  with recursion we don't need to do this
  var result = descending_minus_ascending(num);
  var times=0;
  //keep re assigning result until it's same as num
  while(result !== num){
    console.log(`Try:${times+1}, result:${result}`);
    result = descending_minus_ascending(num);
  }
  return times;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's just that I kind of got lost. If it helps (which I probably shouldn't be saying that) the extent my knowledge is: var, function, return, array, a few .() (I honestly don't know what they are called yet, like split.()), all of the === !== etc, if, for, and while loops, .match, parseInt, parseFloat, and probably some more that is slipping my mind right now. I admit that I didn't fully understand how the push phrases worked, only what they did. I'm sorry, I see what you're doing, just not really understanding how.

Comment: Also, I do not mean to sound rude, but it would be extremely useful for learning, if I knew what was wrong with what I wrote.

Comment: @BradenFoltz the main thing wrong is that you don't use recursion. I have  updated my answer to make it a little simpler and to implement the specifications more precisely.

Comment: @BradenFoltz `const makeAtLeast4 = num =>` in classic JavaScript would be `function makeAtLeast4(num)...` its [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank you, I can work with this. I have a lot to learn, don't I?

Comment: @BradenFoltz That's a good thing, you won't be bored for some time. I've been doing this for 20 years and still learn every day. I think it's best to look into array [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of loops. When you get reduce then you should get recursion as well. Just let me know if you need any help with something.

Comment: Thank you. (it won't let my comment be that short)

Comment: I will definitely look into that, but for now, can you explain my while loop more in depth? You said that I wasn't using recursion (I'm not trying to argue), but I thought that would be recursion. It also seems to me that it is not even starting, because it should at least add one to var result, but it doesn't. I did add a change, though it didn't help. I'm adding it right after this comment.

Comment: I also understand that there is more in there that I have to add to fix, but for now, I just want to get it working, or at least understand what isn't.

Comment: @BradenFoltz `forD-chngdN` both are arrays, you are trying to substract one array from another and that doesn't work (you get NaN which is Not a Number) and NaN is never equal to `trkr` I've added the `kaprekarsConstant` as a while loop but unless you plan to do a lot of C++, C#,Java (and even they are enabling more declarative ways) I'd avoid loops at least for the first 6 months.

Comment: sorry for the long wait, i went to sleep, but I tested that and it worked. Priorly I turned the variables back into strings, and from there into numbers before I subtract. I tested that individually. What doesn't seem to be working is result is not adding each time.

Comment: I changed them into numbers using this <code> forD = parseFloat(forD);
    chngdN = parseFloat(chngdN); </code>

Comment: @BradenFoltz If you write a seperate function that turns a number into another number with the digits sorted ascending or descending then the code becomes a lot more readable. Also you can  use `parseInt` instead of `parseFload` because this doesn't use float numbers, only ints. Your original code has a lot of `var` that are re assigned a lot of times making something simple hard to read. Try to use `const` and splitting the work in smaller functions. You can update your answer with the new code you wrote if you still have trouble to make it work and I'll have a look.